# Android App. Download and use Icons at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, icons, android-view, resolution

I have some questions regarding Icons in our Android App.

We currently have a lot of Icon Sets in the drawable folder (like 20-30 Sets) which we use depending on which user is logged in currently. Each of the Icons exists multiple times for different resolutions (HDPI, XHDPI...). 
We don't like having all the Icons in the App because we need to release a new update every time when we need to add some new Icons (which happens a lot).

---

Question:

**Is it possible to download Icons at runtime and use them to create a view? Then we wouldn't need to store all the Icons in the app.**

**If yes, how would it work with different resolutions? Would we need to download each Icon in different sizes?**

---

Thanks in advance.